# Ruby - print a value out of an arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to print a value out of an array but for some reason can't.
Here's my code:

```
click = rightClick(mat, sel)  #(click is a method that opens an input window. It returns an array of 5 values)
constLib << click

constNum=constLib.length
for i in 0..constNum
  puts (constLib[i][1])
end
```

I get an error saying:

```
Error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
(eval):37:in `block (4 levels) in initialize'
(eval):34:in `each'
(eval):34:in `block (3 levels) in initialize'
-e:1:in `call'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`..` is inclusive. Which means, you're accessing the out of bound index, that is the length of the array. Hence change it to `...` which is exclusive.

However, that's not how rubyists approach it, as they might frown upon you for using for loop. It's better to use `each`

```
constLib.each {|arr| puts arr[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with 5 items, the first item in the array is item 0, and the last item is item 4.

e.g. 0,1,2,3,4

Your for loop needs to go from 0 to (constNum-1), or it needs to use the "..." exclusive operator instead of the inclusive "..".

However, you should consider going through the array using each

```
click = rightClick(mat, sel) 
click.each do |item| {
    puts item[0]
}
```

I've changed the puts to print the first item in the array. This may have been what you were tring to do. This is item[0], and not as I think you originally wrote, item[1].

Answer (score 0):

You should just do `constLib.each {|click| puts click[1]}`